# Using PowerStatus class in windows phone 7 app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am new to windows phone app development.
I am trying to use the powerStatus class in a windows phone 7 app. I have searched quite a bit regarding that and learnt that it is necessary to add reference of System.Windows.Forms
But in the add reference of the project 'System.Windows.Forms' is not present.

How can I use the powerStatus class?

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you need to use the PowerStatus?
like, want to know the power status?
There is also alternate to this class is available.

Comment: I just want to obtain the battery status of the mobile i.e. the percentage of battery left.

Comment: ok.. i will post the Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Refer this msdn link that will clearly shows that how can you get the status of the Battery. i.e. The remaining Percentage of charge in phone;s battery.

[Know the battery status in windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207231)

In this link, use the **RemainingChargePercent()** Method this will return the value that indicates **the percentage of the charge remaining on the phone's battery.**

This things will used in windows phone 8 only.

But, you are with windows phone 7. so, currently there is no API available for windows phone 7 to know the remaining charge in phone's battery.

You will get the information like the if your phone is connected to power source or running in battery.

I will show here some important msdn question links that shows that there is no method or the class is available to get the charge level in windows phone 7.

The MSDN Question link: [how to get the battery status in windows phone 7.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/67c44952-3c6d-40ac-97ae-83cf2b1d6bd9/how-to-get-the-battery-status-of-windows-phone-7-in-c?forum=wpdevelop)

if you have the need to show the battery charge percentage, then i suggest you to proceed with windows phone 8.

Comment: Your most Welcome. Continue journey with windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

It work for wp8. but I am not sure about wp7.

```
_battery = Battery.GetDefault();
var remainingCharge = string.Format("{0} %", _battery.RemainingChargePercent);
var remainingTime = _battery.RemainingDischargeTime.TotalMinutes;
_battery.RemainingChargePercentChanged += OnRemainingChargePercentChanged;


private void OnRemainingChargePercentChanged(object sender, object e)
{
   var remainingCharge = string.Format("{0} %", _battery.RemainingChargePercent);
   var remainingTime = _battery.RemainingDischargeTime.TotalMinutes;

  if(Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.PowerSource == Microsoft.Phone.Info.PowerSource.External)
      var text = "Charger Connected";
  else 
      var text = "Charger Not Connected";
}
```